# File issues with 32 bit application on 64 bit Windows 10 VM

Tags: java, windows, io, virtual-machine

So, I'm running the below code in both a 32 bit and 64 bit application. Both of these are on a 64 bit Windows 10 VM. I want to test the failure if the user enters a filepath they don't have permissions to write to. Running the 64 bit, it fails as expected with the IOException. Running the 32 bit, it doesn't throw an exception at all. Even if I add the additional to check if the file exists, it still acts like it was successful. I've verified that the file never got written to the location.

```
private boolean export(String location, JsonObject jsonObject) {
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(location));
        gson.toJson(json, bw);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception caught in JSON export.", e);
        // Message Box to user
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not closing writer in case of exception, use try-with-resources

Comment: Are you sure logging is working? If you don't see a log file, how do you know it didn't throw an exception, and simply couldn't write the exception to the log file?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Tried that.

Comment: @Andreas It is, I just extracted a small piece of the code. It logs that it tries to write to it and event logs that it successfully finishes.